# Why did Scriabin notate the bass clef in Op 11 no 15?

Tags: notation

Why didn't he just notate it with treble clef from the start?

[image]

Comment: The grand staff ( violon and bass clef) is the definition for keyboard sheet  music. Thats all.
https://musicterms.artopium.com/g/Grandstaff.htm

Comment: I see so, keyboard sheet should have both clefs and then immediately do clef change

Comment: Your question is not „ wrong“. Some composer write in such situations a violine clef for both hands. Especially in this case as it is collection of preludes for piano. I could see a reason: I had  over looked the violin clef in Bartoks mikrkosmos “ in the mist.” My auntie got quite angry and upset about the dissonants. She said: Don’t you see, you’re playing the wrong clef! Thus I changed the clef and the sound was even more awful. Since then I became a Bartok fan: You can annoy aunties.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the sheet music *publisher* is the one who did the typesetting, not the composer.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli *"My auntie got quite angry and upset about the dissonants. She said: Don’t you see, you’re playing the wrong clef! Thus I changed the clef and the sound was even more awful. Since then I became a Bartok fan"* I laughed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grand staff is the definition for keyboard sheet music.

As the title of opus 11 is 24 Preludes for Piano the composer could have notated from the beginning the treble clef.

The two clefs are emphasizing that there is a change of clef.

It might also have been that he had bought empty sheet music paper with prepared grand staffs but it doesn’t seem:

http://www.scriabin-association.com/the-texts-of-scriabins-works-some-observations-of-a-performer-researcher-teacher/